# Identifying Steel Yard Shed and Door Handle to Shed

Tags: shed

My house was built in early 1960s Ontario, Canada, and this shed may or may not be original to the house. I'm having trouble identifying what brand the shed is, and if there might be replacements available for its door handles.

The local hardware store tells me that there are some makeshift solutions I can use, but ideally I find an exact replacement because this will allow me to more easily lock the shed.

Does anyone know how I might go about identifying this shed, and finding a replacement handle? If not, do you know how I'd best go about replacing the handle with something else?

[image: Shed]

[image: Shed Handle]

Comment: It's proprietary and likely no longer made (for a few decades now, though I doubt the shed is from the '60s). Take your hardware store's advice.

Comment: Ours was from the 70s.  Would be a nice DIY job, but local hardware should have something similar enough.  I imagine you lock with a pad lock, even two basic gate type handles will do with a long clasp lock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Unscrew (or drill out rivets/rusted screws) the hardware.

  - Spray some good metal primer on the exposed metal holes.
- Buy replacement hardware that meets your aesthetic & budget requirements.
- Install new hardware.

Finding the exact replacements for original hardware for a shed built anywhere from the 1960s to 1990s is probably not going to happen within a reasonable time frame (like, before that handle rips the rest of the way off), and isn't really required. Heck, depending on your weather that shed could be as little as 15 years old and look like that (harsh winters & hot summers can age things quickly), and you probably still wouldn't be able to find exact replacement.

Sometimes, it's just not worth the effort.

If you *really* want something that looks exactly the same, take the pieces to a local blacksmith or other custom metal fabricator (along with a large wad of cash<sup>*</sup>) and have her make up a duplicate for you.

<sup>*</sup>About 15 years ago, I contacted my local blacksmith to have him punch a couple dozen holes in 2 pieces of aluminum and add 1 bend in each. He wouldn't give me a time estimate, but said it would be $75/hour. I'm sure rates have gone up since.

Comment: Zinc rich primer or "cold galvanizing compound." "Good," like you said.